How do units work out in a magnet's flux density vector field?
I was reading this question about the vector field around a magnet, because it happened to be my question exactly. Only, I didn't like the answer at all. I want a function that returns a vector of the magnetic flux density (the units should be tesla or gauss or something), and I can't for the life of me see how the function provided in that answer is a magnetic flux density.
It seems to me, the $P$ vectors are all points in space, so their units ought to be meters or some distance unit. And when put on the top and bottom of the vector function that should be unitless, not teslas.
I'm also having a hard time believing you can find a solution based on where the north and south poles are, but not how strong those poles are. For example, this neodynium magnet vs this samarium cobalt magnet don't have the same tesla value.
Then there are dimensions of the magnet. Certainly a wider magnet will have a different vector field than a skinnier one.
So how to I get a function to describe a field around a magnet?

From far enough away, any magnet resembles a dipole with the field in surrounding air or vacuum defined as on this wiki page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole
The geometry only matters when you get up close to the magnet.  "Close" and "far" are relative terms, but say, roughly, maybe on the order of 3-4x some characteristic length.
The B-field and H-field inside the magnetic material are somewhat different than outside in the surrounding air.  Those are the Remanence and Coercivity numbers that you see on the links.  They have to do with the shape of the B vs H curve of the material.
If you don't like the units of H (Amps per meter) you can convert to Teslas by multiplying by vacuum permeability constant $\mu_0$.
From the wording of your email and the kind of question you are asking, I think you will find the complete answers are a bit more complicated than you want them to be.

The limit is not how complicated I want it to be, the limit is the size of a reasonable answer here on stack exchange.
I'm motivate. If it's too complex to answer fully here, Can I get a reference to a textbook I can read up on it?

The wikipedia links are actually pretty good.  But another good textbook reference is "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by Griffiths.   Also "Classical Electrodynamics" by Jackson.  Note that as far as I know, the exact solutions for magnetic field around a permanent magnet (including near field) ONLY exist for magnetic spheres or ellipsoid shapes.  All other shapes require some kind of FEM (computer) simulation and/or approximation by a dipole as discussed above.
